# Select2.js no selecciona valor por defecto en DropDown

Tags: angularjs, select2

Buenos dia,

estoy a utilizar select2.full.js y select2.css es un modulo de angular.

El problema es que cuando se muestra el **dropdown** no me aparece el valor seleccionado por defecto en el option. Pero si aparece cuando clico sobre el DropDown alli si aparece el valor seleccionado pero tambien queria que aparezca inicializado cuando es cargado el dropdown.

Voy a poner dos imagenes para que se entienda mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cual es el problema??

Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de como lo pones por defecto el valor, para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

```
<select ng-model="vm.producto.selected">
<option ng-repeat="producto in vm.productos">{{producto.descripcion}}</option>
</select>

vm.productos = [{id:0, descripcion:"producto1"},{id:2, descripcion:"producto2"}];    
vm.producto.selected = vm.productos[0];
```

con esto el producto1 va aparecer por default en el combo ...!!!

Answer (score 1):

El codigo es el siguiente la classe wn_dropdown-box es la que aplica los estilos del select2

```
<div class="wn_dropdown-box">
              <select ng-model="wifiGuestAdvanced.wifiArrayInfo[0].ui_security_type" class="wn_dropdown" style="width: 100%" ng-change="wifiGuestAdvanced.getArrayEncryptionMode(wifiGuestAdvanced.wifiArrayInfo[0].ui_security_type)">
                <option ng-repeat="types in wifiGuestAdvanced.wifiGuest[0].possible_security_types">{{types}}</option>
             </select>
            </div>
```